# Get the value of Count from database rows in ASP.NET web app

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net, oraclecommand

The query is correct but I want to access the number of rows and show in the front-end page. This code is throwing an error.

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString_cw"].ConnectionString;
            OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
            OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(constr);
            con.Open();
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT COUNT (*) from dish";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            DataTable dt = new DataTable("Dish");
            using (OracleDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (sdr.HasRows)
                {
                    dt.Load(sdr);
                    recordMsg.Text = sdr["count(*)"].ToString();
                }

            }
            con.Close();
        }
```

I am using Oracle as database and it is connected already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you need a single value there is no use of `DataTable` and `DataReader` you can simply use `ExcuteScalar` of command and get the values.

```
 command.ExecuteScalar();
```

More Reading https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0

or simply

```
recordMsg.Text=command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```

So the whole code can be written as

```
string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString_cw"].ConnectionString;
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(constr);
con.Open();
cmd.Connection = con;
cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT COUNT (*) from dish";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
recordMsg.Text=command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```

It is also advisable to use `using statement` for better use of command and connection.

Answer (score 1):

Use numeric index for the following line of code

```
recordMsg.Text = sdr["count(*)"].ToString();
```

Change it to...

```
recordMsg.Text = sdr[0].ToString();
```

Or:

Change the two line of code below:

```
cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT COUNT (*) from dish";
recordMsg.Text = sdr["count(*)"].ToString();
```

To read

```
cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT COUNT (*) as rCount from dish";
recordMsg.Text = sdr["rCount"].ToString();
```

Either option should work well for you.
Note: The numeric index is zero because it's a zero-based index. I trust you understand this